# What is the difference in these two methods of selecting first and last data from a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to select the first and the last row of `market_cap` and assign these to `first_value` and `last_value`.  What are the differences between the following two ways?

```
# Select first and last market cap here

##method 1
first_value = market_cap.iloc[0]
last_value = market_cap.iloc[-1]

##method2
first_value2 = market_cap.first('D')
last_value2 = market_cap.last('D')
```

How should I think of them? How are the two out puts different?
(I see that one gives the info vertically and one horizontally but I don't get what is what)

I want to then use `pd.concat()` to concatenate `first_value` and `last_valu`e along `axis=1` and plot the result as horizontal bar chart.

```
pd.concat([first_value, last_value], axis=1).plot(kind='barh')
plt.show()
```

The first method works fine but the last method doesn't give me the graph I want.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may help to give some dummy data, but assume

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[3,4],[5,6],[4,5],[6,7]], index=pd.date_range('2018-04-09', periods=4, freq='1D'), columns=['NFLX','AAPL'])
df
```

gives

```
            NFLX  AAPL
2018-04-09     3     4
2018-04-10     5     6
2018-04-11     4     5
2018-04-12     6     7
```

Your question:

```
> first_value = df.iloc[0]
> last_value = df.iloc[-1]
```

iloc[] returns a series -- just one column which is usually row oriented.  This does get you the first and last, but in series form (1xN dimension).

```
df.iloc[0]
NFLX    3
AAPL    4
Name: 2018-04-09 00:00:00, dtype: int64
```

first() and last()

```
> first_value2 = df.first('D')
> last_value2 = df.last('D')
```

First and last are only for timeseries indexed dataframes, and returns a dataframe not a series.  The 1 column dataframe will be table oriented for 1 row.

```
df.first('D')
            NFLX  AAPL
2018-04-09     3     4
```

Does that help?  You can convert to/from DataFrame to Series depending what you want to do.  Just remember a column slice on its own is a Series and multiple columns is a DataFrame.

Comment: Good explanation, one can also use `df.iloc[0:1]` and `df.iloc[-1:]` to get the same structure than with `first` and `last` :)

Comment: Thank you very much. Just to understand you better, when you say _" The 1 column dataframe will be column oriented."_  what do you mean by  _1 column dataframe_? since as `info()` gives:                                                                                                                
`Data columns (total 2 columns):
NFLX    1 non-null int64
AAPL    1 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(2)
memory usage: 24.0 bytes`  there are **two columns** there.  Also would you please calirfy when you say _column oriented_ and _ is usually row oriented_ what do you mean?

Comment: Actually my explanation was bit off sorry.  You'll find that df.first('D') is the same as doing df.iloc[0:1,:] -- ie, both take a full row w/ all columns and return a dataframe.  while df.iloc[1] also takes 1 row but is represented as a series.  If you wanted 1 column you would do df.iloc[:,0] which also will be represented as a Series.  If you use the range syntax it'll represent even 1 col/row as a dataframe.

Comment: in your response, _The 1 column dataframe will be column oriented._, did you mean the _**The 1 row dataframe**_?